# Copy file and replace variable with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, ejs

I try to copy and replace some variable in multiples files. For this, i use `esj` module replace my vars.

But i don't know if ejs module is correct for my case. I would like just copy "template" initial file and replace variable in file.

My exemple using NodeJS :

```
    const symfonyPluginPath = path.join(
      __dirname,
      '../plugins/symfony/template'
    );
    const testPath = path.join(__dirname, '../plugins/test');
    shell.rm('-rf', testPath);
    shell.mkdir(testPath);
    shell.cp('-r', `${symfonyPluginPath}/*`, testPath);
    shell.cp('-r', `${symfonyPluginPath}/.*`, testPath);
    shell.cd(testPath);

    // @ts-ignore
    fs.readdir(testPath, (error, files) => {
      files.forEach((file) => {
        const compiled = ejs.compile(
          fs.readFileSync(`${testPath}/${file}`, 'utf8')
        );
        const test = compiled({ appName: 'test' });

        console.log(test);
      });
    });
```

This code work for only 1 file, but in `forEach` i've an error `EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read`.

I don't know if my approch is good and if ejs is the correct module for this.

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 0):

EISDIR stands for "Error, Is Directory". This means that NPM is trying to do something to a file but it is a directory. 
Try in this format ---
path.join('x/y/z', '/plugins/test')